# store Recursive function value in array (php)

Tags: php, arrays

I have function to find all parent of child I have created  function i m getting parent id but not able to save in one array and return one array instead only last valu getting inserted . array_push is not working in my case here.

```
function has_parent($parent,$con) {
    $return  = array(); 
        $selectparent = "select * from table where id = $parent ";
        $qResult = mysqli_query($conobj,$selectparent);
        $qRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qResult);
        $parent_id = $qRow['parent_id'];
        if ($parent_id != 0) {
            //$return[] = $parent_id;
            echo $parent_id; // geting parent id as 432 
            $return[] = $parent_id;
            $a = has_parent($parent_id, $con);
        }else{
            return $parent_id;
        }

    return $return;
}

$marray =  folder_has_parent($parent ,$con);
print_r($marray); // getting last array only

Array
(
    [0] => 4
)
```

expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [3] => 2
)
```

Comment: You don't use result of recusion (don't save `$a` variable some where).

Comment: Check link : http://avenir.ro/multi-level-unlimited-menu-php-sub-menus/

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `$return` all the time when you calling the recursive function in the line `$return  = array();`. so instead you should try making the `$return` a global variable hence it is no longer in the function scope.

```
function has_parent($parent,$con) {
    global $return; // global variable
    $selectparent = "select * from table where id = $parent ";
    $qResult = mysqli_query($conobj,$selectparent);
    $qRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qResult);
    $parent_id = $qRow['parent_id'];
    if ($parent_id != 0) {
        //$return[] = $parent_id;
        echo $parent_id; // geting parent id as 432 
        $return[] = $parent_id;
        $a = has_parent($parent_id, $con);
    }else{
        return $parent_id;
    }

    return $return;
}

$return  = array(); // setting the global variable
$marray =  folder_has_parent($parent ,$con);
print_r($marray);
```

Comment: If you don't like `global` may be you can use `$GLOBALS['return']` or `$_SESSION['return']` or write to files.

Comment: using $GLOBALS or $_SESSION for storing temporary variable even worse.

Comment: If you still don't want to use result recursive call then better will be wrap this function to class, and use object internal private variable. Or create inner function inside `has_parent` that will do what current `has_parent` do, but will receive `$return` from scope.

Answer (score 0):

This may be slow because of array_merge, but it will return array in order that you wish.

```
function has_parent($parent,$con) {
    $return  = array(); 
    $selectparent = "select * from table where id = $parent ";
    $qResult = mysqli_query($conobj,$selectparent);
    $qRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qResult);
    $parent_id = $qRow['parent_id'];
    if ($parent_id != 0) {
        $return = [ $parent_id ];
        $return = array_merge( $return, has_parent($parent_id, $con) );
    }    
    return $return;
}
```

This may work faster, but result will be in reversed order

```
function has_parent($parent,$con) {
    $return  = array(); 
    $selectparent = "select * from table where id = $parent ";
    $qResult = mysqli_query($conobj,$selectparent);
    $qRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qResult);
    $parent_id = $qRow['parent_id'];
    if ($parent_id != 0) {
        $return = has_parent($parent_id, $con);
        $return[] = $parent_id;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Of course time required for array copy will be negligible compare to query time, but I'd prefer to use second variant and then run array_reverse. It's more readable (for my opinion).

UPDATE: This function can be easily rewrite to iterative function. Iterative functions easier to understand (meter of taste), and it may work better (at least require less memmory) then recursive.

```
function has_parent($parent,$con) {
    $return  = array(); 
    do{ 
       $selectparent = "select * from table where id = $parent ";
       $qResult = mysqli_query($conobj,$selectparent);
       $qRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qResult);
       $parent_id = $qRow['parent_id'];
       if( $parent_id != 0) {
          $return[] = $parent_id;
          $parent = $parent_id;
       }
    } while( $parent_id != 0 );
    return $return;
}
```